# How do I reset the SFDX CLI Runtime Global Configuration Values?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I had sometime back set the `apiVersion` [CLI Runtime Configuration](http://CLI%20Runtime%20Configuration%20Values) value **globally** for all projects to version 45.0 when I signed up for Spring '19 preview sandbox, using the command:

```
sfdx force:config:set apiVersion=45.0 --global
```

Now whenever I executed any SFDX command, I would see the following message in the console.

> WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "45.0"

While I could have overridden this again locally when say I proceed using future versions, but that would have required me to set this for every local project.

So, how do I **reset the global configuration value** to be applicable for all projects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had struggled to find this for a bit as I missed the section discussing this in the docs. I realized that the answer was in the same documentation [CLI Runtime Configuration Values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_config_values.htm) but was not clearly called out with respect to how to **reset global** values.

The documentation mentions:

> To **unset** a configuration value, set it to no value. For example, to unset the instanceUrl configuration value:
>
> `sfdx force:config:set instanceUrl=`

So utilizing the same approach, I was then able to **reset the global** `apiVersion` that I had set for my SFDX projects using the below command. Note that command to set any global value (using `--global`) can be run from either outside or within a SFDX project directory.

```
sfdx force:config:set apiVersion= --global
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I had my apiVersion set to 48.0 globally, and this was messing up a python script we have for org setup because the message 'WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "48.0"\n' was being construed as an error.  Clearing that out got me all squared away! 

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of SFDX (7.193.2) it should be:

```
sfdx force:config:unset org-api-version --global
```

Answer (score 0):

The newer sf command is:

```
> sf config unset org-api-version --global 
Unset Config
=========================
| Name            Success 
| ─────────────── ─────── 
| org-api-version true    
>
```