# Error retrieve from manifest in Visual Studio

Tags: sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode, sfdx-error

I am trying to Retrieve Source from Org and I get this error:

```
UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL
```

In package.xml, it shows me:

```
<version>54.0</version>
```

With this command `sfdx version`

it shows me

```
sfdx-cli/7.165.0 win32-x64 node-v16.17.0
```

With this command `sfdx force`

```
WARNING: apiVersion configuration overridden at "54.0"
```

and with this `sfdx plugins` ,it show me

```
>> salesforcedx 51.16.0
salesforcedx 52.0.0
├─ salesforce-alm 52.0.0
├─ data 0.4.11
├─ apex 0.2.2
├─ custom-metadata 1.0.12
├─ org 1.6.6
├─ schema 1.0.7
├─ limits 1.2.1
├─ templates 51.5.0
├─ user 1.3.0
└─ @salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test 0.1.7
```

what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [How do I reset the SFDX CLI Runtime Global Configuration Values?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261694/how-do-i-reset-the-sfdx-cli-runtime-global-configuration-values/261695)

Also check the API version specified in your sfdx-project.json file

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks @identigral, I'll update the answer when I'm back at office. Cheers for the tip!

Comment: Hi! the version of the sfdx-project.json is 54.0

Comment: What I did was delete: Visual Studio Code, Salesforce CLI, .vscode folder, .sf folder, .sdfx folder and reinstall everything.